# Index to speed up similarity comparison when all the lines are along a same x-axis?

Tags: postgis, performance, linestring, spatial-index, similarity

When comparing similarity of linestrings with ST_HausdorffDistance (or another type of similarity function), is there a way to use an index to speed up the search for similar linestrings?

Comment: For example to only do the calculation for linestrings that are within a certain distance of each other.

Comment: No, not by distance. The linestrings are all along the same x coordinate, but may vary greatly on the y coordinate. Id like to know if there are any indexes that would narrow down linestrings that are within a range. For example, I would want to select linestrings that match a specific linestring +/- a few points on the y coordinate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the linestring are indeed along the same x but vary on y you can create indices on `ST_YMAX()` and `ST_YMIN()` functions like so:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_ymin_ymax ON places (St_ymax(geom),St_ymin(geom));
```

Next just query the table using `St_ymax` and `St_ymin` in the `WHERE` clause to limit the results.